# Using SIM card info on a USB Card Reader to secure usage of windows software

Tags: security, authentication

i have developed a windows desktop application and it is ready for distribution. Target buyers are in the order of few hundreds only. Yet wishing to protect it from unauthorized use.

First idea was to use something like HASP key etc. Found costly for my case. Then googled about machine fingerprint etc to write my own code. Found mixed opinion about it. Especially the fact that it might not be that end-user-friendly when they upgrade hardware.

Why should the fingerprinting be from machine.. it could be from something else which is unique and yet connected to the machine (hoping sim card is unique), right.? Put a sim card on a usb reader and plug it into the system. The application shall read the sim card id for authentication. Assuming i supply the sim card and pre-code their ids in the application. Is this idea sane and possible?

Thanks, Chandra.

Comment: The cost of distributing the cards will sink your business case. Plus I'm afraid your question is too broad and opinion based. Please do post again if you have any programmin questions when you get around implementing your idea.

Comment: Oh i see.. thanks! Sure, i will post programming questions in the future.. sorry about that..

Comment: If you must implement something, [hash and decrypt](http://rdist.root.org/2007/04/09/mesh-design-pattern-hash-and-decrypt/) works well and can be implemented without any hardware. Implementation cost is not null, though.

Comment: many thanks, i will explore it..